# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model/CPN_Model.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using python 3.9.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AbdiShakra\OneDrive\Documents\Diagnosticc-main\server.py", line 4, in 
import prediction
File "C:\Users\AbdiShakra\OneDrive\Documents\Diagnosticc-main\prediction.py", line 5, in 
model = keras.models.load_model("model/CPN_Model.h5")
File "C:\Users\AbdiShakra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 205, in load_model
return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
File "C:\Users\AbdiShakra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 108, in load
meta_graph_def = tf.**internal**.saved_model.parse_saved_model(path).meta_graphs[0]
File "C:\Users\AbdiShakra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 118, in parse_saved_model
raise IOError(
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model/CPN_Model.h5{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To load a model with tf.keras only pass the directory which contains the model, instead of the .pb or .h5 file itself. `/tmp/saved_model` may be a valid path, while `/tmp/saved_model/mymodel.pb` is not. Check the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) to see some example code.